# FQL: Select date of the last post of all friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to query the date of the last wallpost for each of my friends using FQL.

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT post_id, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

However, this does not provide me with the output I am looking for. Furthermore I wonder how to set the LIMIT?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an v1.0 app, you could use

```
SELECT post_id, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by created_time desc limit 1
```

If you have a v2.0 app, you'll only see the posts of the friend which are using the same app. If you're using >v2.0 then you have no chance to use FQL. In general, FQL will be deprecated on August 7th, 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t get the posts of friends anymore, for privacy reasons. Friend permissions are gone: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

You may want to stop using FQL too, because:

> The FQL and REST APIs are no longer available in v2.1